# How do I make a jQuery script work on Grails?

Tags: jquery, function, grails, groovy, textfield

How do I make a jQuery function work with Grails??

I installed the jQuery plugin and added grails.views.javascript.library="jquery" at the end of conf/Config.groovy

And when I trigger the function I get an error saying

Object Expected

I checked the code and is fine, you can check it out here: http://www.jsfiddle.net/dCy6f/

When I write the number into the textfield I get the error.

Any ideas of what I might be doing wrong?? Or maybe I'm missing something??

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have

```
<g:javascript library="jquery" plugin="jquery" />
```

in the `<head>` section of your view.  Put this in `grails-app/views/layouts/main.gsp` if you want it in all your views.

Comment: Now I don't get an error, but the function does not get triggered :/